# Change Git Parent Branch

Tags: git, branch

Let's say we have a branching structure like:

```
develop   -> --- a --- b --- c
                  \           \
feature 1 ->       \           --- d --- e
                    \    
feature 2 ->         --- f --- g
```

After doing work on feature 1, I decide it really should of been branched off as a sub-task of feature 2.

Is there a way for feature 1 to 'undo' branching off of develop, and branch off of feature 2 instead, while keeping its commits?

Example:

```
develop   -> --- a --- b --- c    
                  \    
feature 1 ->       \         --- d --- e
                    \       /
feature 2 ->         f --- g
```

Comment: in this case a rebase won't work. You could do this:

```git checkout g; git cherry-pick e~2..e```

Comment: An idea might be to construct a `feature_1b` branch from `feature2`, cherrypick the commits `d` and `e`. Remove `feature1` and rename `feature1b` to `feature1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use rebase with `--onto` flag, as described in the [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing#_more_interesting_rebases). The command:

```
git rebase --onto feature2 develop feature1
```

Will rebase commits from `feature1` that are not found on `develop` on top of `feature2`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would look at `git rebase` for this sort of thing, but it's not going to work because a rebase from feature1 onto feature2 would include commits b and c, which you don't want.

Willem's suggestion to use `cherry-pick` is probably the way to go.

Create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b feature1b feature1
```

Cherry pick the commits of interest (here I am saying "the last two commits of feature1", but but you could specify the range of commits using actual commit ids etc):

```
git cherry-pick feature1~2..feature1
```

At this point, branch `feature1b` matches your desired history.  You can perform some optional cleanup, depending on your needs:

Delete the old branch:

```
git branch -D feature1
```

Rename the new branch:

```
git branch -m feature1
```

Comment: `git rebase --onto feature2 develop feature1` will do it in one step, but I admit this is particularly confusing. :-)